# Mock init from import using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm tryin to test some static  methods from a database class that its calling  innit in its file. I want to avoid it so i wont need to have a real conection for the testing, but I'm not able to.

The class is something like:
project/src/store.py

```py
class Store:
    def __init__(
        self, host=None, username=None, pass=None
    ):

        self.store = connection(
            host=host,
            username=username,
            pass=pass
        )

    @staticmethod
    def get_id():
        # stuff

Store()
```

And this is what I tried to prevent  that first innit:
project/tests/test_store.py

```py
from mock import patch
def __init__(self):
    # do something else
    print("Mock init")
with patch('src.store.Store.__init__', __init__):
    from src.store import Store
```

But it just doesn't work. Keeps trying to call connection().

Comment: you should inject your `connection` as a dependency for easier testing and separation of responsibilities, the issue with mocking `__init__` is that it initializes the object from your class so if you mock it, you will just return a `Mock` which is useless to test against

Comment: The ideal `__init__` method just assigns arguments to attributes, and does no actual "work" itself.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should change your code to take in `connection` as a dependency to the `Store` class that way it is easier to test and keep layers separate. To answer your question you will actually need to mock `connection` in order to keep `Store` as the original class and not a `Mock` class.

```
# src/manager.py

class connection:
    def __init__(self, host, username, password):
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self._password = password
        self.id = f"testing_{self.username}"

class Store:
    def __init__(
        self, host=None, username=None, password=None
    ):

        self.store = connection(
            host=host,
            username=username,
            password=password
        )

    def get_id(self):
        return self.store.id


# tests/test_manager

from unittest.mock import patch


def test_store_init():
    with patch("src.manager.connection") as mock_conn:
        from src.manager import Store
        mock_conn.return_value = mock_conn
        mock_conn.id = "fizzbuzz"

        store = Store("abc.com", "user", "pwd")

        assert store.get_id() == "fizzbuzz"
```

---

```
================================================================= test session starts =================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: ***
plugins: asyncio-0.18.3, hypothesis-6.48.1, mock-3.7.0
asyncio: mode=strict
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                      

tests/test_manager.py .

================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ==================================================================
```

Comment: Why not go one step further and have the *caller* create the `connection` instance to pass as a single argument to `Store`? You can provide a *class* method like `def from_info(cls, host, user, pass): return cls(connection(host, user, pass))` to keep `__init__` simpler for testing.

Comment: that works as well, in general we are both recommending that the current approach is not advised

Answer (score 0):

Little or nothing about this answer applies if you don't have control over your `Store` class (e.g., it's a third-party library). But if you do have control over its design, read on.

---

The ideal `__init__` method doesn't do anything except assign arguments to attributes. This means instantiating an object does as little work as possible, allowing you to control how "expensive" your setup will be.

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.store = connection

    @staticmethod
    def get_id():
        # stuff

s = Store(connection(host, username, pass))
```

To provide the convenience of creating the connection for you, the class should provide an additional *class* method as an alternative constructor.

```
class Store:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.store = c

    @classmethod
    def from_info(cls, host, user, pass, conn_factory=connection):
        c = conn_factory(host, user, pass)
        return cls(conn_factory(host, user, pass))

    @staticmethod
    def get_id():
        # stuff

s = Store.from_info(host, username, pass)
```

Now there is no need to patch anything for testing. You can pass an appropropriate stub/mock/etc to `Store` directly, and you can pass an appropriate stub-mock-etc factory as an argument to the class method to avoid creating a real DB connection.

```
fc = FakeConnection(user, name, pass)
s1 = Store(fc)
s2 = Store.from_info(host, user, pass, FakeConnection)
```